# failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

Tags: node.js, websocket, hosting

I developed a node.js application using socket.io

Locally I have no problem, but once hosted (with o2switch), I get this error in console when I try to connect in websocket:

failed: One or more reserved bits are on: reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 1, reserved3 = 1

have you encountered this problem before? I have no way to solve it :(

Comment: Hello, Have you find a solution ? I'm on o2Switch too, and I've got same error...